# Thumbnail directory name

Tags: files

I'm creating a video hosting website, the thumbnails are uploaded manually, because i couldn't configure ffmpeg because of shared hosting. I would like to retrieve a videos thumbnail from the server, but every thumbnail is in an oddly named directory. For example I have a video node with the id of 32, now the respected thumbnail is in a directory like this:
/public_html/sites/default/files/videos/thumbnails/108. I would like to know how drupal creates that '108' directory, based on what?

Comment: What folder is it configured to save to?

Comment: are you using a module like 'File (Field) Paths' to set the paths?

Comment: And are you using media module or something like that? I'm guessing that is the file id, since technically the file doesn't exist on your server it exists somewhere Drupal's system will still give it a file id or that is the manually uploaded thumbnails file id, you could relate the video and thumbnail together with an entity reference so you would know the thumbnail id when pulling the video node.